# Pedir nombres con prompt y almacenarlos en un array en javascript

Tags: javascript

Se supone que debe pedir 3 nombres con prompt, usar un array para almacenar y después  mostrar sus valores.

```
function names() {
    var nombres = [];
    var cont;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        var x = prompt("Ingresa tu nombre:", "");
        nombre[i] = x;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        cont += nombres[i] + " ";
    }
    document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = cont;
}
```

Comment: Buenas tardes Victor, te recomiendo pasar por aquí [ask] para ver como tienes que formular la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: @victormanuelorozcocovarrubi te aconsejo que primero uses console.log(cont), una ves que veas que todo va bien en consola, prosigues a imprimir o lo que quieras hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Habían un par de errores pero si estás aprendiendo es lo normal. Fíjate que he usado `push` para añadir al final del array los nuevos elementos y que he inicializado `x` antes de entrar en los `for` puesto que se va a usar varias veces y no es correcto inicializarla en cada vuelta

Aquí tienes una versión posible, espero que te sea útil:

```
function names() {
    var nombres = [];
    var cont = '';
    var x;

    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        x = prompt("Ingresa tu nombre:", "");
        nombres.push(x);
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        cont += nombres[i] + " ";
    }

    document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = cont;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. En los bucles `for`, donde dice `int` debes usar `var`: En javascript las variables no son tipadas y no existe un tipo `int`, los números usan `Number` pero esto es automatico.
2. Cuando capturas los nombres el nombre del arreglo está mal: dice `nombre` pero la variable se llama `nombres` (en plural)
3. la variable `cont` debe estar inicializada por  que luego usas el operador `+=`. Sino quedaria "undefined" al inicio de la cadena.

Salu2

```js
function names() {
    var nombres = [];
    var cont = "";
    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        var x = prompt("Ingresa tu nombre:");
        nombres[i] = x;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        cont += nombres[i] + " ";
    }
    document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = cont;
}

names();
```

```html
<div id="here"></div>
```

Comment: lo mas recomendable es usar let, ya que con var sigue existiendo la variable fuera de su ambito

Comment: @rn3w que la variable valga fuera del ambito no es problema salvo que crees un closure (una funcion dentro del for), y usar `let` es incompatible con muchos navegadores que hay por ahi dando vueltas. Si usas `let`, deberias usa un transpiler para hacer el codigo comptible hacia atras.

Comment: @m3w Lo que dices es "cierto", pero necesita ciertos matices. La variable no sigue existiendo fuera de su ámbito: su ámbito es su ámbito y no sigue existiendo fuera de él. Lo que pasa es que con `var` el ámbito es la función en la que se define y no el bloque (lo cual puede confundir); mientras que con `let`, el ámbito es sólo el bloque en el que se define.

Answer (score 0):

Tambien podés evitar algunas líneas, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
function names() {
  var nombresList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    var nombre = prompt("Ingresa tu nombre:");
    nombresList.push( nombre ); 
  }
  /* Con Join podemos unir los item de la lista */
  document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = nombresList.join(" ");
}

names(); // Iniciar la función
```

```html
<div id="here"></div>
```

Con `nombresList.join(" ")` podemos unir los items de la lista, si colocamos un guión en vez de colocar un espacio entre las comillas unirían los items con guiones... `nombre-nombre-nombre`

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que la variable cont no tome como valor: **undefined**, entonces podrías aplicarlo de esta manera, usando una condicional **if**:

```
function names(){
    var nombres = [];
    var cont;
        for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
        var x = prompt("Ingresa tu nombre: ");
        nombres[i] = x;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
        if (cont === undefined){
            cont = "";
        }
        cont += nombres[i] + " ";
    }
    document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = cont;
}
names();
```

También podrías inicializarlo, sin embargo saldría junto con los valores del array.

Comment: Quizá lo que quieras es definir variables locales. `var` define variables globales mientras que `let` locales.